# Are SAS folders logical folders or physical folders

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

When I open up the SAS data integration studio, I see a 'Folders' tab which has a folder structure. Now, when i right click and see 'Properties' for a folder,  I see something called a 'Location'.

This location is not mapping to a physical folder location on the SAS server. So is thsi just a logical fodler structure? Where are the physical fodlers that it corresponds to?

Comment: I'd ask this @ communities.sas.com if you haven't already; Unless DomPazz knows, I don't think anybody else regular around here uses DI.

Answer (score 2):

The folders structure is a logical structure in the SAS metadata to organise the SAS metadata. Most objects to not exist outside the SAS metadata, so they have no corresponding  physical location.

A few metadata objects store elements outside the metadata (eg. Web Reports). Each folder has a mapped content location in the SAS content server where such elements are stored. This physical mapping only applies if you have the BI Server and usually does not affect metadata objects created in DI Studio.